# how to print each Index of my JSON Fetched Files?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach, typescript

I have a lists of Tables that is being displayed as seen here in the image:

[image: Encircled Red is the problem]

Encircled Red is the problem wherein I want to display the Index of each JSON array as my Table number.

Here's my code:

```
function getExternal() {
   fetch('https://kyoala-api-dev.firebaseapp.com/queue-group/5e866db4-65f6-4ef0-af62-b6944ff029e5')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
         let reservationList = '';

         res.forEach(function (reservation) {
            reservationList += `
            <tr>
               <th scope="row">Table</th>
               <td class="text-center">${reservation.minCapacity} - ${reservation.maxCapacity}</td>
               <td class="text-center">${reservation.activeQueuesCount}</td>
            </tr>`;
         });
         document.getElementById('lists').innerHTML = reservationList;
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: The forEach iterator gives you (reservation, index), just update to include the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you need to use `index` from the `forEach` function, it will give you the current `index` of the item you are at that moment.

below you have the change added:

```
function getExternal() {
   fetch('https://kyoala-api-dev.firebaseapp.com/queue-group/5e866db4-65f6-4ef0-af62-b6944ff029e5')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
         let reservationList = '';

         res.forEach(function (reservation, index) {
            reservationList += `
            <tr>
               <th scope="row">${index}</th>
               <td class="text-center">${reservation.minCapacity} - ${reservation.maxCapacity}</td>
               <td class="text-center">${reservation.activeQueuesCount}</td>
            </tr>`;
         });
         document.getElementById('lists').innerHTML = reservationList;
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: Thank you sir.... so my code was kinda wrong, I've tried what you did in the function part like this: function(index, reservation) so reservation must be the first parameter then index would be the next as you did. thanks a lot.